# Browser Detection Download

Tags: browser, download, detection

looking for some help with a rather unique or interesting issue. I am currently in the process of creating a website and would like to implement the following.

1. I have a download button where the end user can click download - Easy enough.
   The complicated part is achieving the following
2. I would like to provide (automatically) the correct file for the user based on their operating system, so if the user is using windows and clicks the download button the windows file will be downloaded, and the opposite applies for mac.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. But this question is much too general. SO users like to see more specific questions, ideally with some attempt at solution on the part of the questioner. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: You can't do OS detection reliably through a browser. This is not a unique issue, it's just impossible by design.

Comment: thanks for the reply, surely this can be done though? if companies like team viewer are able to provide a file based on OS? i.e https://get.teamviewer.com/z6jnkme